# Magento 2: Change the "URL Key" and save the category "The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists."

Tags: category, save, magento2.3.5-p1, url-key, multistore-view

When change the "URL Key" and save the category then throw the below error.

This store Migrate Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3.5-p1 and used multi store view.

**Error:**

```
The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.
To resolve this conflict, you can either change the value of the URL Key field (located in the Search Engine Optimization section) to a unique value, or change the Request Path fields in all locations listed below:

- fitness-equipment/strength/kettlebells.html

- fitness-equipment/strength/dumbbells.html

- fitness-equipment/strongman/hammer.html
```

**I have try below solution but not fixed the issue:**

**Solution 1)**

```
    - Truncate the url_rewrite table. 
    - Generate category url via https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites module
    - use command for genrate the category url: php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate --entity-type=category
```

**Solution 2)**

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259845/migration-tool-causing-url-rewrite-duplicates-in-magento-2-leading-to-missing-ca
```

**Solution 3)**

```
- Install module for remove duplicate: https://github.com/cadencelabs/urldedup
    - Generate category url via https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites module
- use command for genrate the category url: php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate --entity-type=category
```

**Solution 4)**

```
- When save edit "URL Key" and save the category then show the error list url.
- I have open that all error url in separate window and delete it.
- Then Generate category url via https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites module
- use command for genrate the category url: php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate --entity-type=category
```

But still getting same error after implement above four solution. If any have idea about this critical issue then let me know.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all `url_path` attribute values from the database, there likely is a duplicate there and they are not used any longer.

Look in `eav_attribute` table to find the `url_path` field's `attribute_id` for both categories (`entity_type_id` 3) and products (`entity_type_id` 4). I'll use X and Y for those since you *really* don't want to use some random values from the internet.

Once you have those, delete from the corresponding tables `catalog_category_entity_varchar` and `catalog_product_entity_varchar`:

```
delete from catalog_category_entity_varchar where attribute_id = X;
delete from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = Y;
```

After this, try your url regeneration again, or re-saving your category with the url key you're looking to use.

Comment: Not able to find `url_path` please check.